# Very long download times for 3D PDF files from SharePoint 2013

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We're currently experiencing very long (@4 to 90 minutes) download times for some (but not all) of the 3D PDF files in one of the libraries in our SharePoint 2013 on premise Document Control site. It doesn't have anything to do with file size, since one of the offending files is 21 megabytes and we can get 150 megabyte files to download in 1 second. To further complicate things, sometimes the offending files will download in 1 second, though so far that only happened on June 1. We checked for beginning of the month and weekly recurring maintenance tasks but so far we can't correlate anything.

We've tried setting up "download a copy", that doesn't work. We've tried moving the files out of the Document Control site and/or the library, but that's not an option.

Comment: Try another browser to download the task?